# How to use Linq and lambda expressions on a Dictionary<string, List<T>> to a specify its order based on Key

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So I have a Dictionary with string keys, and the value is a List of objects.  Each object in each List has a property value which is equal to that List's associated key.  In other words, the Dictionary is grouping objects by property value via the key.  For example, let's say we have,

```
Dictionary<string, List<Animal>> GroupedByClass = new Dictionary<string, Animal>();
```

Where Animal is an object which contains a string property named "ClassType" which has valid options of "Mammal", "Reptile", or "Amphibian", etc.

The Animal class could also have string property named "Species" which more uniquely defines each object in the Dictionary.

A pseudocode description of the contents of the Dictionary could be:

```
<"Mammal", List<Animal>>
```

where the Animals in the list have Species "Dog", "Cat"
    <"Reptile", List>
where the Animals in the list have Species "Snake", "Lizard", and "Turtle"
    <"Amphibian", List>
where the Animals in the list have Species "Salamander" and "Frog"

I want to rearrange this Dictionary by the key value such that the values with a key of "Reptile" are first, then "Amphibian", and then finally "Mammal".  Note that I do not want to sort this based on alphabetical order, I want to specify my own order.

I know I could solve this problem by simply iterating through the Dictionary a few times, extracting only the items with the right key.  For example, I could do it like this,

```
Dictionary<string, List<Animal>> temp = new Dictionary<string, List<Animal>>();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<Animal>> item in GroupedByClass)
{
    if(item.Key == "Reptile")
    {
        temp.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<Animal>> item in GroupedByClass)
{
    if(item.Key == "Amphibian")
    {
        temp.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<Animal>> item in GroupedByClass)
{
    if(item.Key == "Mammal")
    {
        temp.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}

return temp;
```

However, this seems inelegant, and I was wondering if there was a better answer for this problem using Linq queries and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be close (with some syntax errors):

```
var order = new [] {"Reptile","Amphibian","Mammal"};
var elems = dict.OrderBy(x=>order.IndexOf(x.Key));
```

if you want to flatten the results, then you can use SelectMany:

```
var order = new [] {"Reptile","Amphibian","Mammal"};
var elems = dict.SelectMany(x=>x).OrderBy(x=>order.IndexOf(x.Species));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, List<Animal>> temp = new Dictionary<string,List<Animal>>();
(new List<string>() {"Reptile","Amphibian","Mammal"}).ForEach(x => temp.Add(x, GroupedByClass[x]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an enumeration and have it be your defining order.

```
enum Animal : int
{
    Reptile = 0,
    Amphibian = 1,
    Mammal = 2
}
```

Note, since you have simple strings this works and is straight forward. If however you end up with strings that have spaces you can use the DescriptionAttribute of the enumeration and go between it and the actual enumeration.
[Enumeration with Display String](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/273687/Enum-Display-Extension)

By using an enumeration over the string you can do many things, but of course order by it using the integers you assiged.