# c# updating a value inside a List<int> thats inside a dictionary<string, List<int>> using Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

Hey all I have a issue with trying to use Lambda with my variable simply because its not a `Key, value` type of setup. Meaning I don't have the typical `Dictionary<string, int>`. I have a `Dictionary<string, list<int>>)`-kind of setup.

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> sizeOfPhotoBoxes = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
    {
        { "box1", new List<int> {357, 272, 8,  5 } },
        { "box2", new List<int> {357, 272, 4,  5 } },
        { "box3", new List<int> {365, 460, 37, 6 } },
        { "box4", new List<int> {365, 265, 8,  6 } },
        { "box5", new List<int> {715, 455, 15, 11 } },
        { "box6", new List<int> {360, 465, 98, 6 } },
        { "box7", new List<int> {360, 465, 44, 6 } },
        { "box8", new List<int> {360, 465, 28, 6 } },
        { "box9", new List<int> {540, 290, 39, 9 } },
        { "box10",new List<int> {540, 290, 10, 9 } }
    };
```

As you can see I have a **Dictionary** with a key that's a **string** and then for its **value** I have a **List** that has 4 **int** values.

I've [seen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36223/creating-a-dictionary-of-strings-and-list-of-strings/36224) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032294/how-to-use-linq-and-lambda-expressions-on-a-dictionarystring-listt-to-a-spe) [examples](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb0c6330-953a-4bcb-8594-d4e0f66a42dd/select-list-items-from-listltdictionarygt-not-matching-values-from-listltstringgt?forum=csharpgeneral) of something similar to mine above but I can not seem to get the value I want from with in the list part.

```
foreach (var _data in sizeOfPhotoBoxes.Where(w => w.Value.Equals("box2")))
{
    _data.Key[2] = 35; //updating the value in the 3rd place in the list
}
```

I can get the **value** since that's the **normal key of the dictionary** but after that I am at a loss. And the error is:

> CS0200    Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Also tried this that produces the same error as the above one:

```
 var _data = sizeOfPhotoBoxes.Where(w => w.Key == "box2").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Value = 35);
```

But that too did not work.

I am wanting to **update box2's list value** that is the **2nd** in the list of the 4 without updating all of them.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I was able to get it by following Snales suggestion:

```
sizeOfPhotoBoxes.Where(w => w.Key == "box2").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Value[2] = 351);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_data` is a tuple of `string, List<int>`. Ergo, you want to use `_data.Value[2]` to get access to the `List<int>` inside of the tuple. The `Key` represents the `"box**"` part.

It might be clearer to change the `var` to the actual type:

```cs
...
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> _data in sizeOfPhotoBoxes.Where(w => w.Value.Equals("box2")))
...
```

Comment: Following your example I was able to come up with the update in my op. Thanks @Snake!

Answer (score 2):

Was able to update via following without loop:

```
sizeOfPhotoBoxes["box2"][1] = 4;
```

Comment: "2nd in the list" is [1]

Comment: your saying key value pair index where key is box2 set the second indices of the list to 4

Comment: Thanks for the help @CaiusJard . To clarify I said 2 because it’s a zero-based list array so that would be { 0, 1, 2, 3 } where the 2 value is what I needed to change. With the example I gave that value would be 4.

Answer (score 0):

There you go!

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> boxes = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
{
    { "box1", new List<int> {357, 272, 8,  5 } },
    { "box2", new List<int> {357, 272, 4,  5 } },
    { "box3", new List<int> {365, 460, 37, 6 } },
    { "box4", new List<int> {365, 265, 8,  6 } },
    { "box5", new List<int> {715, 455, 15, 11 } },
    { "box6", new List<int> {360, 465, 98, 6 } },
    { "box7", new List<int> {360, 465, 44, 6 } },
    { "box8", new List<int> {360, 465, 28, 6 } },
    { "box9", new List<int> {540, 290, 39, 9 } },
    { "box10",new List<int> {540, 290, 10, 9 } }
    };

    var box2 = boxes.Where(box => box.Key.Equals("box2")).FirstOrDefault();
    
    Console.WriteLine(box2.Value[1]);
        
    box2.Value[1] = 400;

    Console.WriteLine(box2.Value[1]);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

In the first example you were trying to change the Key, not the value.

Not sure about the second one, but here you have an example.